# strange behavior when using list of another class objects as class attribute in python

Tags: python, list, class, attributes

I am having some issues with the classes below:

```
class book:
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.name=name
        return
    
class bookshelf:
    def __init__(self,books=[]):
        self.books=books
        return
    def add_book(self,name):
        self.books.append(
            book(name)
        )
        return
```

Next, I initialize list a list of bookshelves:

```
bookshelves = [bookshelf() for i in range(3)]
```

With all of them empty, both `bookshelfs[0].books` and `bookshelfs[1].books` are `[]`.

However, after adding a book to the first bookshelf,

```
bookshelves[0].add_book('Book1')
```

all books have a book named "Book1": both `bookshelves[0].books[0].name` and `bookshelves[1].books[0].name` have the value `'Book1'`.

This does not change even after I reinitialize the list of `bookshelf`. But if I rerun the section defining the classes, the `bookshelf`s will be cleared.

Any ideas how does this happen? How should I implement this part correctly? By the way, I am running Python 3.8.3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Mutable Default Arguments are counter-intuitive!
Python creates the list once when the method is defined not when it is called. Therefore the list obj is shared between instances. [Here's](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) A good article on the issue.

I would instead remove the default argument and check/set it in the init method.

```
class bookshelf:
    def __init__(self,books):
        self.books = []
        if books:
            self.books = books
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and pointing out this pitfall to me. It's really helpful.